# Why use "eslint-plugin-prettier" over "eslint-config-prettier"

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

Both [eslint-config-prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-prettier) and [eslint-plugin-prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prettier) are popular packages for integrating **ESLint** with **Prettier**.

However, after reading Docs of both of them I understood that both would do the job. But, if we use **eslint-plugin-prettier**, there will be a [few issues](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#arrow-body-style-and-prefer-arrow-callback-issue) that would not happen if we would use **eslint-config-prettier**. Also, when using **eslint-plugin-prettier** recommended config, it would use **eslint-config-prettier** behind the scene.

It seams to me that **eslint-config-prettier** has obvious advantages over  **eslint-plugin-prettier**, but **eslint-plugin-prettier** is still very popular and it has really a lot of weekly downloads on **npm**. Did I miss something? What would be advantage of using **eslint-plugin-prettier**?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 6):

This packages have different purposes:

- **eslint-plugin-prettier** - runs Prettier as an ESLint rule and reports differences as individual ESLint issues.
- **eslint-config-prettier** - turns off all rules that are unnecessary or might conflict with Prettier. It's mean that if you use some eslint-config(your own or third party) and this config have conflicts with prettier rules - it should resolve this conflicts by turn off this rules.

Comment: What does it mean `Runs Prettier as ESLint rule`? What is the difference between running it as a rule and running it normally?

Comment: It's mean that you can run prettier as eslint rule if you use eslint. Prettier is independent tool. But there are have integrations with different linters - eslint, tslint, stylelint etc.. If you use some of them - you can add plugin for your linter and avoid install prettier additionally.

Comment: I see. So I don't have to install Prettier editor extension locally in order for Prettier to work. ESLint will format my code as Prettier would with it's rule?

Comment: Yes. But how it's describe in documentation - it's not recommended. You can read about it here - https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html#notes